# Can't get Artifacts using Build runner type Visual Studio Solution File

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I am new to TeamCity. I am using Build step using Visual Studio solution file. I want to configure Artifact path so that I can get the output of my compilation somewhere in Artifact folder. I could't understand from the TeamCity documentation :)

I have following configuration. But not getting any artifact.

```
Artifact paths:- /MyProject/bin/Release/*.* => PublishDir
Build Runner : Visual Studio(sln)
Build file path: \Successor\Successor.sln
Targets: Rebuild
Configuration: Release
Platform: x86
```

Whats wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would edit your artifact and build paths as follows:

```
Artifact paths: MyProject/bin/Release/*.* => PublishDir
Build file path: Successor\Successor.sln
```

Sometimes paths references with '\' or '/' leading into it can cause issues with TeamCity. Updating your artifact path could solve the problem. Obviously, editing the build file path will not fix your problem, but it would be a good idea to go ahead and change this in case you ever edit the configuration.

If this change does not help, what do the log files say about the your build results? Did your build results successfully make it into the Project/bin/Releases folder on the build agent? Is there any reference to the artifacts being published or failing to be published in the logs?

Answer (score 5):

Check the TeamCity Build Log. It will tell you, why no artifact could be created. For example:

```
[Publishing artifacts] Artifacts path /MyProject/bin/Release/*.* not found
```

Make sure your files are really compiled ro `bin\release`.